# MyBB - PHP regex

Tags: regex, pcre, mybb

I have the following regex.

```
\[rep=([0-9]*?),([0-9]*?)\]([\w#]{4,11}),([\w#]{4,11}),([\w#]{4,11}),([\w#]{4,11})\[\/rep\]
```

To me this seems perfectly valid - it's meant to match for instance the following string:

```
[rep=0,20]#fff,#fff000,#111,transparent[/rep]
```

And while it does seem to work in, for instance, RegExr, the MyCode for it just doesn't seem to trigger.

Comment: have you tried playing with it in https://www.regex101.com ?

Comment: What is `MyCode`? What is your PHP usage?

Comment: @Martin, it works in regex101.com.

Comment: @chris85 MyCode is a version of BB-Code for MyBB forum system.

Comment: ok, so the issue is not regex then, but is how your PHP code uses the regex.

Comment: You need to show us the PHP line of code that this regex is used on for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. The hashes `#` had to be escaped.

`\[rep=([0-9]*?),([0-9]*?)\]([\w\#]{4,11}),([\w\#]{4,11}),([\w\#]{4,11}),([\w\#]{4,11})\[\/rep\]`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not putting the [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) in your PHP implementation.

```
if( preg_match("/\[rep=([0-9]*?),([0-9]*?)\]([\w#]{4,11}),([\w#]{4,11}),([\w#]{4,11}),([\w#]{4,11})\[\/rep\]/", $str) ) {

}
```

https://eval.in/568814

Comment: I had thought that to start with but playing with it on regex101 only worked on the assumption that the OP had negated to include the full code, only displaying their actual query string (without delimiters).